# jquery - convert attribute based on class selector to a list of ints

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i have a number of divs with the **class="mydiv"**

each of these divs also has an attribute **id** which is **set to a number**

i want to basically say (pseudo code)

**select all divs with class = "myDiv"

loop through them and get the id attribute

combine all ids into a list and return an array of these integers**

is this the best way of doing that?

```
 var ids = new Array();
 $(".myDiv").each(function (i) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    ids[i] = id;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.myDiv[id]').map(function() { return this.id });
```

will give you an array like object which you can treat as an array ( for loop ) of ids.

Comment: That'll make a list of strings. I'm guessing the original poster wants a list of ints, so I'd update to `return Number(this.id)`.